# Свой toolbar для каждого Fragment'a

Tags: android, android-fragment

Использую несколько фрагментов, для которых есть отдельный тулбар. При добавлении тулбара подсвечивается в студии ошибка "activity.getSupportActionBar.setTitle() may produce java.nullpointerexeption". При этом фрагмент грузится, но все действия залипают, на другие фрагменты он не переходит. Прошу подсказать в чем ошибка?

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_three,container,false);
    Toolbar profile_toolbar = (Toolbar)view.findViewById(R.id.profile_toolbar);
    AppCompatActivity activity = (AppCompatActivity)getActivity();
    activity.getSupportActionBar().setTitle("dgdfg");
return view;
}
```

UPD. Ошибка крылась в использовании FragmentTabHost, почему-то вид с фрагментом залипал на фрагменте с использование тулбара. Пришлось заменить FragmentTabHost на TabHost

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Это не ошибка, а предупреждение `Android Studio` т.к. при определенных условиях метод `getSupportActionBar()` может вернуть `null` и вот тогда уже случится `NullPointerException` в вашем приложении. Чтобы это исключить, достаточно выполнить проверку на `null`. Тогда и студия перестанет пугать этим сообщением.

```
ActionBar actionBar = activity.getSupportActionBar();
if(actionBar!= null) {
    //какой то код
}
```

Из-за этого скорей всего и залипают ваши фрагменты, т.к. вы только нашли `ToolBar`, но не установили его, потому `getSupportActionBar()` возвращает  `null`. Попробуйте сделать так:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_three,container,false);
    Toolbar profile_toolbar = (Toolbar)view.findViewById(R.id.profile_toolbar);
    AppCompatActivity activity = (AppCompatActivity)getActivity();
    activity.setSupportActionBar(profile_toolbar);
    ActionBar actionBar = activity.getSupportActionBar();
    if(actionBar!= null) {
        actionBar.setTitle("dgdfg");
    }
    return view;
}
```

Comment: toolbar и actionbar? зачем такой комбомикс?

Comment: "Ругательство" студии ушло, но залипание осталось. Внутри вида любое действие можно совершить, а по вкладкам tabHost'a не переходит. Так в этом виде и висит.

Comment: @IvanVovk покажите код как вы меняете фрагменты

Comment: @iFr0z чтобы не делать лишних приведений типов при установки заголовка, т.к. методы активити работают с ActionBar'ом